# How to alter title of present tab using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to change the title of a tab using extension.Actually i got stuck up at using

chrome.tabs.get(function(tabs){...

How to use the above function?
is there another way i can directly change the title?

Answer (score 12):

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
   function(tab){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:"document.title = 'My lame title!'"});
   }
);
```

The above will change the title of the currently selected tab.  If you allready know the id of the tab you want to change, then its....

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{code:"document.title = 'My lame title!'"});
```

..where tabId contains the tab.id of the tab that you want to change.

Answer (score 11):

The title isn't a property of the tab, but of the page inside the tab. Adjusting a page's title, however, is certainly possible: one mechanism would be to inject a content script that effected `document.title`:

```
document.title = "My awesome title!"
```

For details, take a look at the content script documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: i think thats because 
"document" in "document.title"here is not related to the present tab

Comment: That's correct: you'd need to inject a content script into the tab for it to be effective. See the sample code that PAEz provided below, which is a bit clearer about the step by step.