# C# Display different text on hover tooltip for browser tab

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to change the text that appears when you hover a tab in a browser. For example:[image]

I want the tag text to stay the same but be able to change the grey text that appears when you hover over it.

The reasoning for this as due to having a site on a clustered server. I want the main tab to remain the same to avoid confusing users but to help support issues by showing the server the site is in the hover part.

I have my server name in a view bag like so:

```
 ViewBag.ServerName = System.Environment.MachineName;
```

Is what I am after feasiable can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Every browser has its own implementation of tabs, so a cross-browser implementation is probably not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're looking for unfortunately cannot be achieved (at least in current browsers displaying HTML). The text shown in the hover tooltip is not controlled directly by the document, but by the browser. For example, Chrome (as do all browsers I know of) displays the full contents of the `<title>` tag when you hover the tab name.

I suppose you could hack a solution by changing the `title` when the document body is out of focus, but at that point you should consider whether there's a better solution for what you're *actually* trying to do.

If you only need to support Chrome, control the user's computers (e.g. in an enterprise environment) and really *really* need this behavior, you could create your own Chrome extension which does this ([*How to alter title of present tab using chrome extension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270782/how-to-alter-title-of-present-tab-using-chrome-extension)).

Comment: Exactly what i was thinking

Comment: Interesting idea thanks for the link, I like it. I do need to support IE mainly but also chrome. I may have to back down on my idea and either show the server name on the page in a string or have it in the tab

Comment: @Phil3992 I think this is more of an UX issue. I would suggest that you take the time to think about *why* and *when* a user might need to know the server name, and think about presenting it in a suitable fashion. Note that there is a StackExchange site for User Experience: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I fear besides the title tag you cannot change anything up there, because the browser handles that by itself plus every browser does it differently.